# Unpacking nested tuples using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I have a list:

```
path = [
    (5, 5),
    'Start',
    0,
    ((5, 4), 'South', 1),
    ((5, 3), 'South', 1),
    ((4, 3), 'West', 1),
    ((4, 2), 'South', 1),
    ((3, 2), 'West', 1),
    ((2, 2), 'West', 1),
    ((2, 1), 'South', 1),
    ((1, 1), 'West', 1)]
```

I am trying to extract all the directions (except for the first one that says 'Start') so that I have a new list:

```
directions = ['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'South', 'West']
```

I have tried the following:

```
for (x, y), direction, cost in path[1:]:  # [1:] to omit the first direction
     directions.append(direction)
```

The result is: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

I have also tried unpacking by using the following:

```
result = [(x, y, direction, cost) for (x, y), direction,cost in path[1:]]
```

It gives the same error. The tuple within a tuple within a list is really confusing me. Thanks in advance for any insight, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just reformatted the code in the question for readability and accidentally made the problem a lot more obvious: The first three elements of the list aren't in a tuple. Use `path[3:]` instead of `path[1:]`.

The reason you're getting that error "too many values" is that it's trying to unpack `'Start'`, which is 5 long, not 3.

```
>>> [direction for (_x, _y), direction, _cost in path[3:]]
['South', 'South', 'West', 'South', 'West', 'West', 'South', 'West']
```

Comment: thank you! lol I feel silly but yes, this works brilliantly!

Answer (score 3):

Did you notice that the element with `Start` is actually three elements?
When encapsulating the first three elements in a tuple, you'll get it right:

```
path = [
    ((5, 5), 'Start', 0),
    ((5, 4), 'South', 1),
    ((5, 3), 'South', 1),
    ((4, 3), 'West', 1),
    ((4, 2), 'South', 1),
    ((3, 2), 'West', 1),
    ((2, 2), 'West', 1),
    ((2, 1), 'South', 1),
    ((1, 1), 'West', 1)]

result = [(x, y, direction, cost) for (x, y), direction, cost in path[1:]]
print(result)
```

out:

```
[(5, 4, 'South', 1), (5, 3, 'South', 1), (4, 3, 'West', 1), (4, 2, 'South', 1), (3, 2, 'West', 1), (2, 2, 'West', 1), (2, 1, 'South', 1), (1, 1, 'West', 1)]
```